# Rolling count on varying window sizes in R

Tags: r, rolling-computation

I have a table with almost a million rows. I want to apply a rolling count of strings/"event" based on Date AND Category. So far, I was able to get the counts of events within each month and category using `dplyr`:

`df %>% group_by(Date, Category) %>% mutate(n_distinct(event))`

I want to be able to modify this code so I can perform a rolling count based on specified window. I do have a column called "Num_Months" and it is category-specific (ex: Category A would be 6 months, category B would be 3 months, Category C would be 12 months, etc).

I have looked into the `slider` package and "slide_index" seems like a good function for me to use as it's index specific, but how would you include it in this code? I'm open to other options/solutions as well!

Data:
`df<- structure(list(Date = c("01-01-2020","01-01-2020", "01-01-2020", "01-01-2020","01-01-2020","01-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "03-01-2020", "03-01-2020", "04-01-2020", "04-01-2020", "05-01-2020", "05-01-2020"),  Category = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "B", "C", "A", "C", "A", "B" ), Num_Months = c(6,6,6,3,12,12,6,3,3,3,12,3,12,6,12,6,3), Events= c("event1a", "event2a", "event1a", "event1b", "event1c", "event2c", "event3a", "event2b", "event3b", "event3b", "event3c", "event4b", "event4c", "event4a", "event5c", "event5a", "event 5b")), row.names = c(NA, 17L), class = "data.frame")`

The results would be something like this:
`result <- structure(list(Date = c("01-01-2020","01-01-2020", "01-01-2020","02-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "03-01-2020", "03-01-2020","04-01-2020", "04-01-2020", "05-01-2020", "05-01-2020"),  Category = c("A",  "B", "C","A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "A", "C", "A", "B" ), rolling= c(2, 1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4, 5,5,4)), row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the dates are being used as an indirect way to represent year/month since all the days are 01 so we convert to yearmon class which represents a year/month internally as year + fraction (Jan = 0, Feb = 1/12, ..., Dec = 11/12).  Then sort, reduce rows with the same Category and Date to one row with the number of distinct events and then perform a rolling sum using rollapplyr.  It supports vector widths and we use the expression shown to compute those widths.  Finally sort the result to be in the same order as shown in the question and select the columns desired.

```
library(dplyr, exclude = c("filter", "lag"))
library(zoo)

df %>%
  mutate(ym = as.yearmon(Date, "%m-%d-%Y")) %>%
  arrange(ym, Date, Category) %>%
  group_by(Category, ym, Date) %>%
  summarize(rolling = n_distinct(Events), 
    Num_Months = first(Num_Months), .groups = "drop") %>%
  group_by(Category) %>%
  mutate(rolling = rollapplyr(rolling, 
    1:n() - findInterval(ym-(Num_Months+1)/12, ym), sum)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  arrange(ym, Category) %>%
  select(Date, Category, rolling)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   Date       Category rolling
   <chr>      <chr>      <int>
 1 01-01-2020 A              2
 2 01-01-2020 B              1
 3 01-01-2020 C              2
 4 02-01-2020 A              3
 5 02-01-2020 B              3
 6 02-01-2020 C              3
 7 03-01-2020 B              4
 8 03-01-2020 C              4
 9 04-01-2020 A              4
10 04-01-2020 C              5
11 05-01-2020 A              5
12 05-01-2020 B              4
```